# VBA Form Control Button Needs to Disappear After Another Button is Clicked

Tags: excel, vba

So I have a Form Control Button NOT and ActiveX Command Button that I want to make disappear when another button is clicked. Normally if it was a ActiveX Command Button i would use:

```
ButtonName.Visible = False
```

in the code that was triggered by the other button. However I dont know how to get that work with a Form Control Button as they dont have name like a ActiveX Command Button does so far as I know?

I would just change the button I want to disappear to a ActiveX Command Button but when I do that I have issues with the buttons format changing, text sizes up when they are clicked, buttons change size when clicked, etc.

---

Comment: Is the button on a sheet or a userform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.Shapes("button 1").Visible = False
```

Answer (score 3):

You may also try

```
Sub Button2_Click()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Buttons("Button 1").Visible = False
End Sub
```